# calculating time averaged data in matlab

Tags: matlab, average, trigonometry

I have a vector of data (named ydot) and a vector of time, when I plot ydot versus time, I get a figure like sine function which is periodic, how can I calculate time averaged ydot?

the following codes calculate exact values of ydot and time:

```
T=(2*pi)/(160e6)
tspan=linspace(0,2*T,1500)
current=linspace(0,1e-6,40);
for k=1:length(current)
f = @(y, t) (current(k)/3.2911e-016)-(2.6151e+009)*sin(y)+(4.8448e+008)*sin(y+0.5697)+(5.2266e+008)*sin((160e6)*t)*cos(y);
[t{k}, y{k}] = ode45(f,tspan,2e22);
end
y1=cell2mat(y);
t1=cell2mat(t);
for k=1:length(tspan)
for j=1:length(current)
ydot(k,j)=(current(j)/3.2911e-016)-(2.6151e+009)*sin(y1(k,j))+(4.8448e+008)*sin(y1(k,j)+0.5697)+(5.2266e+008)*sin((160e6)*t1(k,j))*cos(y1(k,j));
end
end
```

this gives ydot for 40 different currents, the following code will plot ydot/time for a specific current(k) (where k=1:40):

```
plot(t1(:,k),ydot(:,k))
```

Comment: Presuming you want some sort of moving average: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/data_analysis/filtering-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean what one assumes to be a time average you could simply get this by taking the mean of ydot like

```
x = 0:0.1:10; % define time
ydot = sin(x); % get some data for ydot
average = mean(ydot); % use mean function to get time average
plot(x, ydot, x, average); % plot both, average (which should be approximately zero for this sine and ydot vs x
```

If not, you need to specify your task more clearly.

Comment: I need to get average in one period, and I don`t know the exact value of period.

Answer (score 0):

If the time-values are equidistant lhcgeneva's solution will be ok.
If not, you'll simply have to write down the appropriate integral, e.g. via trapz:

```
time_averaged_mean = trapz(time, ydot) ./ (time(end) - time(1));
```